# nginx configuration for frontend+api on same server with removing index.php

Tags: nginx

I did configuration for frontend it's work fine
Also api's index.php reach properly when called directly to index.php but other urls of api called it routed to frontend's index.php below is the code, much appreciate, I'm new to nginx world

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  abc.com;

       # Certificate
       ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/abc.com.pem;

       # Private Key
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/abc.com.key;
    root   /var/www;
    location ^~ /api/v1 {
        root /var/www/apps/api/v1;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /apps/api/v1/index.php;
    }
    index  index.html index.php;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess order or try_files $uri $uri/ /apps/api/v1/index.php; is the issue

Comment: it's solved relocated location